# Storing products in order - product is deleted after order placed

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, product

I have an orders table, which currently stores the product ID and the quantity.

However, should the product be removed from the site, then when getting the data for the order, there won't be a relationship between the order and products (product no longer exists).

What is the best way of rectifying this? Do I need to store the product name etc with the order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend hard deleting your products in the first place.

Instead you can soft delete them by adding an extra `bool` to your products table named `deleted` and put that to `true` when deleting a product. This way you keep your references to old, deleted, products.

> Note that you will have to change your SELECT query to include `WHERE deleted = false`. So you only get the products that aren't deleted.

This is also usefull if you accidently delete a product which you didn't want to delete. Because you can easily change it back.

Comment: What would you suggest if those products can also have options?

Comment: @RyanHipkiss What do you mean with options? If you mean another table referring to them, then my suggestion stays the same. As long as you are referring to those products in any other table it's best never to actually delete them. You just have to think by yourself. "Would I need any of the product data after it's deleted?" If the answer is yes, soft delete. When you're not sure, soft delete. Only delete if you're really sure you'll never need the data again.

Comment: @RyanHipkiss If the answer helped you with your question, could you accept the answer?

Comment: As an alternative name for the flag, perhaps "In Stock/Out of Stock" might work.

Answer (score 0):

Some systems (*) deal with this problem exactly as you indicated in your question - by copying the product name (and other relevant data) to the order, so that the order will still have all the information in it even if the product is deleted.

(*) For example, both OpenCart and Zen Cart do this.